# Error while checking the latest version of pip

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install some packages with pip and getting error

```
pip install docker==2.7.0
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement docker==2.7.0 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for docker==2.7.0
```

With `-vvv` option:

```
HTTPError: 403 Client Error: TLSv1.2+ is required for url: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/json
```

Few days ago there was no such problem

pip version: `pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)`

Comment: http://pyfound.blogspot.com/2017/01/time-to-upgrade-your-python-tls-v12.html

Comment: Does the error still exists if  you try using `sudo` in front of pip

Comment: @Stivan yes, it still exists

Comment: @kichik Seems like solution. I use python 2.7.10 so I'll try to upgrade to 2.7.14 and try again

Comment: @kichik Upgrade python2.7 and Openssl has not helped

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in old openssl linked to system python.
So I've uninstall all python distribs from system and install last python with `brew install python@2`

One can check openssl version linked to python like that

```
Python 2.7.14 (default, Mar 22 2018, 15:04:47)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
'OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python -
```

This worked for me, Mac Sierra 10.12.6... https://github.com/pypa/packaging-problems/issues/130

Comment: I've already seen this issue but it didn't worked for me