# pip3 suddenly could not install any package in mac book pro

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Today when I tried to install some package using pip3 command with mac book pro M1 chip, shows error like this:

```
> pip3 install jurigged
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', IsADirectoryError(21, 'Is a directory'))': /simple/jurigged/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', IsADirectoryError(21, 'Is a directory'))': /simple/jurigged/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', IsADirectoryError(21, 'Is a directory'))': /simple/jurigged/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', IsADirectoryError(21, 'Is a directory'))': /simple/jurigged/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', IsADirectoryError(21, 'Is a directory'))': /simple/jurigged/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jurigged (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jurigged
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

my internet connection are working fine, why still show this error? what should I do to fixed this issue? this OS is macOS 13.2. this is the pip info:

```
> pip3 -V
pip 22.3.1 from /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
```

I have tried to use pyenv to manage the virtual environment, but still could not fixed this issue:

```
> pyenv virtualenvs
  3.10.11/envs/ai-hub (created from /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.pyenv/versions/3.10.11)
* ai-hub (created from /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.pyenv/versions/3.10.11)
```

I did not found any proxy settings in shell:

```
> env|grep proxy
> env|grep PROXY
> env|grep "PROXY"
> env|grep "proxy"
```

did not found any proxy settings in pip:

```
> pip config list
> pip3 config list
```

this is the verbose output:

```
> pip3 install jurigged --verbose
Using pip 22.3.1 from /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', IsADirectoryError(21, 'Is a directory'))': /simple/jurigged/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', IsADirectoryError(21, 'Is a directory'))': /simple/jurigged/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', IsADirectoryError(21, 'Is a directory'))': /simple/jurigged/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', IsADirectoryError(21, 'Is a directory'))': /simple/jurigged/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', IsADirectoryError(21, 'Is a directory'))': /simple/jurigged/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jurigged (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jurigged
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

I also tried to switch the mirror like this:

```
> pip3 config set global.index-url https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple
Writing to /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.config/pip/pip.conf
> pip3 install --upgrade setuptools


Looking in indexes: https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (58.1.0)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', IsADirectoryError(21, 'Is a directory'))': /pypi/web/simple/setuptools/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', IsADirectoryError(21, 'Is a directory'))': /pypi/web/simple/setuptools/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', IsADirectoryError(21, 'Is a directory'))': /pypi/web/simple/setuptools/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', IsADirectoryError(21, 'Is a directory'))': /pypi/web/simple/setuptools/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', IsADirectoryError(21, 'Is a directory'))': /pypi/web/simple/setuptools/
```

still did not work. This is the detail log output:

```
> pip3 install jurigged -vvv
Using pip 23.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
Non-user install because site-packages writeable
Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/pip-build-tracker-q7p480sj
Initialized build tracking at /private/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/pip-build-tracker-q7p480sj
Created build tracker: /private/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/pip-build-tracker-q7p480sj
Entered build tracker: /private/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/pip-build-tracker-q7p480sj
Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/pip-install-jwkwgaf4
Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-5awll4_s
Looking in indexes: https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple
1 location(s) to search for versions of jurigged:
* https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple/jurigged/
Fetching project page and analyzing links: https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple/jurigged/
Getting page https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple/jurigged/
Found index url https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple
Looking up "https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple/jurigged/" in the cache
Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): mirrors.ustc.edu.cn:443
Incremented Retry for (url='/pypi/web/simple/jurigged/'): Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', IsADirectoryError(21, 'Is a directory'))': /pypi/web/simple/jurigged/
Starting new HTTPS connection (2): mirrors.ustc.edu.cn:443
Incremented Retry for (url='/pypi/web/simple/jurigged/'): Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', IsADirectoryError(21, 'Is a directory'))': /pypi/web/simple/jurigged/
Starting new HTTPS connection (3): mirrors.ustc.edu.cn:443
Incremented Retry for (url='/pypi/web/simple/jurigged/'): Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', IsADirectoryError(21, 'Is a directory'))': /pypi/web/simple/jurigged/
Starting new HTTPS connection (4): mirrors.ustc.edu.cn:443
Incremented Retry for (url='/pypi/web/simple/jurigged/'): Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', IsADirectoryError(21, 'Is a directory'))': /pypi/web/simple/jurigged/
Starting new HTTPS connection (5): mirrors.ustc.edu.cn:443
Incremented Retry for (url='/pypi/web/simple/jurigged/'): Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', IsADirectoryError(21, 'Is a directory'))': /pypi/web/simple/jurigged/
Starting new HTTPS connection (6): mirrors.ustc.edu.cn:443
Could not fetch URL https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple/jurigged/: connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mirrors.ustc.edu.cn', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi/web/simple/jurigged/ (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', IsADirectoryError(21, 'Is a directory'))) - skipping
Skipping link: not a file: https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple/jurigged/
Given no hashes to check 0 links for project 'jurigged': discarding no candidates
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jurigged (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jurigged
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 348, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 173, in _add_to_criteria
    raise RequirementsConflicted(criterion)
pip._vendor.resolvelib.resolvers.RequirementsConflicted: Requirements conflict: SpecifierRequirement('jurigged')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 481, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 350, in resolve
    raise ResolutionImpossible(e.criterion.information)
pip._vendor.resolvelib.resolvers.ResolutionImpossible: [RequirementInformation(requirement=SpecifierRequirement('jurigged'), parent=None)]

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 419, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 101, in resolve
    raise error from e
pip._internal.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for jurigged
1 location(s) to search for versions of pip:
* https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple/pip/
Fetching project page and analyzing links: https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple/pip/
Getting page https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple/pip/
Found index url https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple
Looking up "https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple/pip/" in the cache
Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): mirrors.ustc.edu.cn:443
Could not fetch URL https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple/pip/: connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mirrors.ustc.edu.cn', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi/web/simple/pip/ (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', IsADirectoryError(21, 'Is a directory'))) - skipping
Skipping link: not a file: https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple/pip/
Given no hashes to check 0 links for project 'pip': discarding no candidates
No remote pip version found
Removed build tracker: '/private/var/folders/1p/dz3r2rz55kd60_t8sgslkvvh0000gn/T/pip-build-tracker-q7p480sj'
```

I also tried to switch the official url, still did not work.

Comment: did your conda env activate fully?  is that the path to the current python?

Comment: I also tried conda deactivate and rerun the command, still could not solve this issue. I active the conda fully.

Comment: Can you add a verbosity flag to pip install command and put the output into your question?

Comment: I have pasted the verbose output.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem on mbp M1 too. And my environment:

- Python Version: 3.10.0, installed by pyenv
- System Version: MacOS 14.0 (23A344)
- OpenSSL Version: OpenSSL 3.2.0 23 Nov 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.2.0 23 Nov 2023)

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748494/11897778) is not work for me, so I have to try to solve by myself. I debug the pip main file and step in to inspect where is wrong.

```
/my-library-location/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/__main__.py install requests
```

Finally, I found **my problem is caused by file missing**, the file which `SSLKEYLOGFILE`  point to was deleted when I clean my system a few days ago. and the resolution is to create that file. for me ,the file path is `/my-user-location/tmp/keylog.log`

Answer (score 0):

I got a macbook pro M1 too. My suggestion is to change to a virtualenvironment on pyenv. It is easy to install and i haven't got any problem in 2+ years using MacOS.
Simple steps:
https://akrabat.com/creating-virtual-environments-with-pyenv/

Other solution:
Run in terminal: `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python`

To avoid other install errors, make sure you also upgrade setuptools after doing the above:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748494/11897778)

Comment: I have tried what you said, still did not fixed this problem.

Comment: @Dolphin is the problem happening to any "pip install" package? or is it only for the 'jurigged' package?

Comment: any new package, not just `jurigged` package.

Comment: @Dolphin and you haven't done anything before the error? (upgrade of OS, change venv, upgrade pip, change internet connection, VPN, proxy) ?

Comment: I placed a new solution. You can also check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49749621/11897778 .

Comment: it looks like the anaconda issue, the conda broke the env.@Jesus Fung

Comment: I have tried to uninstall the anaconda but still did not fixed this issue.

Comment: @Dolphin was the issue solved? what have you tried? :)

Comment: No, I did not fixed this issue. I have tried reinstall python10, using the mirror address, but still could not fixed this issue.